# input text with icon on the left and border

Tags: html, css, input

I'm still newbie in html. How can I achieve this with style:

- rounded border 1px color grey
- icon on the left with peach background
- input text on the right

[image: required input text]

Comment: Being a newbie doesn't exempt you from explaining, and showing, your own attempts, and explaining where they went wrong. Please, show us your code (even if it doesn't work) and explain where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better If you can provide some code but since you are a beginner hope this code helps you

```
<div id = 'outer'>
    <div id = 'inner'>
        img
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#inner{
    position:relative;
    width: 20%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius:2px;
    z-index:-30;
}
```

Cick for fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apr6yLqq/)

Comment: this is so far is the most closest solution. Thanks Anjula

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve that as Crossbrowser solution is to use `background-image` with `background-position` and `background-size`

```css
input[type=text]{
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/EitD5gR.png);
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  border-radius: 6px;/*rounded border */
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding-left: 16px
}
```

```html
<input type=text />
```

in a near future you will be able to do that using `:pseudo-element`

Comment: Yes, and with input field relative position or margin manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea:

The rounded border you'll get with the CSS property `border-radius`. You'll need to look this up, because not all browsers respect plain ol' `border-radius` - you'll end up with several css rules (e.g. `border-radius:...; -webkit-border-radius:...`). The border color you'll get with the css property `border-color`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp (and the links in the left sidebar) is a good resource to learn about styling borders

The image inside the input is going to be kinda complicated for a newbie. There are a couple ways you could do this… I recommend using a :before "pseudoelement." You'll set the <input> (or whatever the main element you're styling here is) to let elements inside it position themselves relative to it, and then you'll set the pseudoelement to be absolutely positioned all the way on the left. The pseudoelement then gets a specific size, and you put an image into it.

Without doing too much of the work for you, the CSS will be something like

```
input {
    border-radius: ...;
    border-color: ...;
    position: relative; <-- lets us position child elements relative to this one
}
input:before {
    content: url(path/to/the/image);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px; <-- I'm just guestimating that number
    height: 100%; <--- depending on the rest of your css, this might need to be set in pixels
}
```

Other problems you might run into:

You might lose the rounded corners on the left. If so, you can round only those corners on the input:before (a tool like http://border-radius.com/ will help you round only certain corners)

If you're using an <input>, it might look wrong in some browsers. That's because browsers supply default styles for inputs. This gets into fancier stuff, so I'll give you the solution up front and you can study up to figure out what it does

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    border-repeat: repeat;
}
```